# Lower Bound of a matrix function

Tags: matrices, optimization

Let $f:(0,\infty)\times S^{n-1}\to\mathbb R$ be a function defined as $$f(t,v)=|(I+tN)v|$$ where $I$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix and $N$ is a nilpotent matrix. We have to show that $\exists c>0$ such that $f(t,v)>c$ for all $t,v$.

Answer (score 1):

I will show that the result is true in the more general case where $t\in \mathbb R$. Assume it's not. Then there exist $(t_i, v_i) \in \mathbb R \times S^{n-1}$ such that $t_i N v_i - v_i \to 0$.

By compacity of the sphere, there is exists a subsequence (not relabeled) such that $v_i \to v$. For this subsequence:

$$t_i N v_i \to v, \quad \|t_i N v_i\|_2 \to 1, \quad \text{and} \quad t_i v_i^TNv \to 1$$
From the first statement, we deduce that $|t_i|\to \infty$, otherwise we would have for a bounded subsequence $\lim_{k\to \infty}t_{i_k} N v = \lim_{k\to \infty}t_{i_k} N v_{i_k} + t_{i_k} N (v -v_{i_k}) = v + 0$, i.e. $v$ would be an eigenvector of $N$ with nonzero eigenvalue, which is impossible by nilpotence of $N$.

Then the second statement implies that $\|Nv\|_2= \lim_{i\to \infty} (1/t_i) \|t_i N v_i\|_2 = 0$, so $v$ is in the kernel of $N$. But then this contradicts the third statement of the first equation because:
$$ t_i v_i^T(Nv) = t_i v_i^T (0) = 0.$$

Comment: Your proof looks very good. I have a confusion though. Can you please explain why $v^TNv=0$ implies $v\in\ker N$? and why that will imply $t_iv^TNv_i=0$ for all $i$? Thanks.

Comment: Oh you're right, there are errors in the proof. I'll think about it. Thank you!

Comment: I think I fixed it. As it stands, the proof is not really clear though, so I'll try to come back to it later when I'll have more time.